# Concurrent ASP.NET Requests to asmx web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an application which is designed in ASP.NET and is consuming asmx web services. I am not using any postbacks but calling page methods through jquery . and in the code behind I am calling the web service. See the sample call below :

```js
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'loginId': loginId, 'password': pass}),
                url: 'Default.aspx/VerifyLogin',
                success: function (d) {
                    debugger;
                    if (d.d == 'OK') {
                        window.location = "Home.aspx?uq=" + d.d;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Username/Password missing or wrong");
                    }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(error);
                }
            });
```

Everything works fine when there are less number of users accessing the application.

My users are inserting some data in to the database based on some other data. When multiple users are accessing the application then there is issue of data mismatch. Suppose "X" is updating data for something say "A" an another user "Y" updating data says "B", then the created or updated by for data "A" is changed to "Y".

what should I change in the code to prevent such kind of issues when multiple user updating data at same time.

Comment: what you said should not happen. each post is  considered a diff request. Have you used any static variables in your web service?

Comment: I dont have any static fields but I am getting the session value from HttpContext.Current.Session . Is it possible that when two concurrent requests comes theHttpContext.Current.Session may get overridden ?

Comment: There isn't enough here to give an answer. The relevant code is what is running on the server, not the client.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use time stamp for updating data or Optimistic Concurrency 
please see the below link

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4811/ASP-NET-Optimistic-Concurrency-Control

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not updating anything. I am only inserting data,